# Android SQLite display item "details"

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

In my project I have a SQLite DB with different rows. Right now I have a `ListView` that displays certain items of this database. Only the  rows **name** and **city** (in code named **taskName** and **taskDate**) are displayed in  these list items. Now I want to display a "detail" page of these items when you click them. So the detail page should contain/display all rows of the item clicked, not only "name" and "city". So far I have done this, but just the name and city are displayed in the detail activity via `.getText()`.
These 2 rows I'm getting with `intent.putExtra()`, but I don't know how to display the other rows, because I can't access them with `.getText()` as they are not displayed in the `ListView`.

This is the code for my `ListAdapter` (if you need more code please tell me) :

```
public class ServiceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ServiceItem> {

    private List<ServiceItem> taskList;
    private Context context;

    public ServiceAdapter(Context context, List<ServiceItem> listItems) {
        super(context, R.id.listitem_taskitem, listItems);

        this.context = context;
        this.taskList = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_task_list, null);
        }

        ServiceItem task = taskList.get(position);

        if (task != null) {
            TextView taskName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
            TextView taskDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.task_date);

            taskName.setText(task.getCity());
            taskDate.setText(task.getName());
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

This is the detail activity so far:

```
public class ServiceDetails extends Activity  {

    private TextView city;
    private TextView name2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setupUI();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = extras.getString("name").toString();
        String description = extras.getString("description").toString();

        city.setText(name);
        name2.setText(description);
    }

    private void setupUI() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_details);

        city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailName);
        name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailWww);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your main activity where you register the `listview` `adatper` ? coz u have to get row information from `listview.setOnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have no idea on what you are doing :P
You have a ServiceItem list provided to your adapter and you view it.

When these items contain all the data fetched from database - then you can pass serialized object or all it's data to `ServiceDetails` activity.

When these items contain only information about name and city you have 2 options:

- Fill this data when you fill name and city (when it's not too big)
- In the ServiceDetails activity get object from database by it's name/id or anything you can grab.